# Host signalling server on heroku

Tags: node.js, webrtc

I have built a signalling server using webrtc, nodejs, web-socket.
I am able to run the server locally but i want to host the server on heroku.
O have looked all over the internet but i cannot find anything relevant.
How can i host this server on Heroku?

Here is my code

```
var WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server;

var wss = new WebSocketServer({port: 9090});

var users = {};

wss.on('connection', function(connection) {

  console.log("User connected");

  //when server gets a message from a connected user
  connection.on('message', function(message) {

    var data;

    //accepting only JSON messages
    try {
      data = JSON.parse(message);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log("Invalid JSON");
      data = {};
    }

    //switching type of the user message
    switch (data.type) {
      //when a user tries to login
      case "login":
      console.log("User logged", data.name);

      //if anyone is logged in with this username then refuse
      if(users[data.name]) {
        sendTo(connection, {
          type: "login",
          success: false
        });
      } else {
        //save user connection on the server
        users[data.name] = connection;
        connection.name = data.name;

        sendTo(connection, {
          type: "login",
          success: true
        });
      }

      break;

      case "offer":
      //for ex. UserA wants to call UserB
      console.log("Sending offer to: ", data.name);

      //if UserB exists then send him offer details
      var conn = users[data.name];

      if(conn != null) {
        //setting that UserA connected with UserB
        connection.otherName = data.name;

        sendTo(conn, {
          type: "offer",
          offer: data.offer,
          name: connection.name
        });
      }

      break;

      case "answer":
      console.log("Sending answer to: ", data.name);
      //for ex. UserB answers UserA
      var conn = users[data.name];

      if(conn != null) {
        connection.otherName = data.name;
        sendTo(conn, {
          type: "answer",
          answer: data.answer
        });
      }

      break;

      case "candidate":
      console.log("Sending candidate to:",data.name);
      var conn = users[data.name];

      if(conn != null) {
        sendTo(conn, {
          type: "candidate",
          candidate: data.candidate
        });
      }

      break;

      case "leave":
      console.log("Disconnecting from", data.name);
      var conn = users[data.name];
      conn.otherName = null;

      //notify the other user so he can disconnect his peer connection
      if(conn != null) {
        sendTo(conn, {
          type: "leave"
        });
      }

      break;

      default:
      sendTo(connection, {
        type: "error",
        message: "Command not found: " + data.type
      });

      break;
    }

  });

  //when user exits, for example closes a browser window
  //this may help if we are still in "offer","answer" or "candidate" state
  connection.on("close", function() {

    if(connection.name) {
      delete users[connection.name];

      if(connection.otherName) {
        console.log("Disconnecting from ", connection.otherName);
        var conn = users[connection.otherName];
        conn.otherName = null;

        if(conn != null) {
          sendTo(conn, {
            type: "leave"
          });
        }
      }
    }

  });

  connection.send("Hello world");
});

function sendTo(connection, message) {
  connection.send(JSON.stringify(message));
}
```

Above is the code sample of server.js file.

Any help will be appreciated?

Answer (score 0):

Here it is:

Step1: Push you code on github.
Before pushing make changes in your package.json.

Package.json is really important file to run your server on any cloud. Mainly start script, dependencies and node version is important. 
Also in your code use process.env.PORT instead of any hard coded port number.

Step2: Create a heroku project through cli. 
Now push you branch on heroku.

I know this is pretty brief steps. But I can help you more. If you are able to do it then good,  otherwise I can help you in detail.